# Is there any way to attach a ContentVersion file to an approval process email?

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template

So there's an approval process and C-suites don't want to click into salesforce anymore to view the related files they just want them attached. I have some experience with Visual force, but haven't touched it in 3 years since the move to lwc. My googlefu led me to believe that a visual force email template OR a VF component imbedded in an email template (however that works) is the path forward.

Apex wise I know how to get the files I want and the only reference I've seen to attachments is the Messaging.EmailFileAttachment so i've done this :

```
public static List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> contentDocumentAsAttachement(Id quoteId) {
    List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> attachments = new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment>{};
    List<ContentVersion> documents                  = new List<ContentVersion>{};
    
    documents.addAll([
        SELECT Id, Title, FileType, VersionData, isLatest, ContentDocumentId 
        FROM ContentDocument 
        WHERE isLatest = true 
        AND LatestPublishedVersion.FirstPublishLocationId =: quoteId
    ]);

    for (ContentVersion document: documents) {
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();

        attachment.setBody(document.VersionData);
        attachment.setFileName(document.Title);

        attachments.add(attachment);
    }

    return attachments;

}
```

but how do i get those files into an email template that can be used in a standard approval process?

Everything i've seen online in reference to VisualForce email templates is simply people creating PDFs/CSVs from salesforce record data and attaching those to an email template via a VF component. So most of what ive seen so far has been unhelpful. On the other end i've seen people send attachments but it's via apex emailing. The problem with that is this is a standard approval process i'm trying to add attachments to.

Comment: the [VF doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_sending_attachments.htm) has a full example of how to do this

Comment: from what i can see it's simply taking existing salesforce object record data and putting it into a visual force page and turning that into a attachment. It's not taking something from the contentversion object and attaching that to an email template used in something like a workflow rule/approval process.

Comment: ah, right - you need the VF email template to include `messagingAttachment`s that represent the ContentVersion data - and this only works for text and HTML; [sfdcfox comment on this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/196476/2602) suggests a workaround

Comment: wow. I'm really surprised salesforce totally lacks this feature unless you create a template to pass a static file as an attachment. My mind it totally blown this can't be resolved with apex.